# Repetitve DB value

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find in a row of my table all the values that are repetitive, e.g. `123text123text` (there might be a line break between the repetitive sub-strings.

So I need an SQL query that tells PhpMyAdmin to return all instances were sub-string first half of value == sub-string second half of value.

**--UPDATE** I don't think i need regex for my query it just needs to select values from the row were sub-string from begin until half of string equals sub-string from half of string until end
Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (String handling may differ...)

Comment: Not 100% sure but try `SELECT columnname FROM table WHERE columnname LIKE "%123text%123text%"` (will be slow on big tables)

Comment: 123text was an example the values will be any string just they will be written twice 123text123text, 567more567more, 75756vvdvbb75756vvdvbb, ect...

Comment: I voted to close your question as too broad because there are many aspects that you should address in your explanation. The strings will be exactly half? What if an string cames as "12ab12ab12ab" half of it will be "ab12ab" which does not repeat; When you say a line break you mean is it a column type Text with bigger texts or what? Please consider in add your tables structure alongside withe sample data so we can understand better

Comment: the string will be exactly doubled there might be a \n inserted in between the doubled text. This is not a complicated cell just a plain value in a row of a DB table I am not familiar with the syntax to do this kind of query so I was asking for a pointer

Comment: I think you would need to look at `mysql REGEXP`.. here is a [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504621/mysql-regular-expression-search-with-no-repeating-characters) that has examples related to repeating patterns.. not exactly your scenario..

Comment: i don't think i need regex for my query just needs to say select values from row were substring from beging until half of string equals  substring from half of string until end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok it was as simple as

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE substring(column, (length(column)/2)+1) like substring(column, 1, (length(column)/2)-1)
```