# Mysql select where same value twice in same field

Tags: mysql

I have a cell that has
`'200 Example Avenue
209 Example Avenue'` in it.

I'm not sure how the line break gets in there.
I would like to run a query on the table that says:
**IF** the content till the line break **matches** the text after the linebreak, then **delete** the text after the line break.

I'm not sure where to start - any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: The lines don't match in your example. Typo?

Comment: If you just want to know if the value appears twice, maybe simply use `WHERE column LIKE '%value%value%'`. You can replace the middle `%` to match a line break, for example `CONCAT('%value', CHAR(10), 'value%')`. I have not tested anyway.

Comment: You can probably use MySQL's [string functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) to pull out the parts before and after the newline, and compare those. I am thinking instr to identify the location of the newline, and mid to pull out the parts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repetitve DB value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205519/repetitve-db-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the 2 substrings before and after `char(10)` and if they are equal keep only the 1st substring:

```
update tablename
set value = left(value, instr(value, char(10)) - 1)
where 
  value like concat('_%', char(10), '%_')        
  and                               
  left(value, instr(value, char(10)) - 1) = right(value, length(value) - instr(value, char(10)))
```

Change `value` to your column's name.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6Nbxr5iCYxGEJGWftr56KJ/0).

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP_SUBSTR to extract the cell value up to and after the newline respectively, and compare both values. For example

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columname = TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(columname,".*\n")) 
WHERE TRIM(TRAILING '\n' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(columname,".*\n")) = 
           TRIM(LEADING '\n' FROM REGEXP_SUBSTR(columname,"\n.*"))                                 
;
```

For example : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/81juEza4M9QAtRpdLagWhh/0#&togetherjs=QbvSuquqwk

Comment: `REGEXP_SUBSTR` not recognized